# c++ pass array directy to function

Tags: c++, arrays, g++, parameter-passing

```
  bool foo(const char* arg, const char* str[]){
    for (int i=0; i < (signed)sizeof(str); i++){
      if(strcmp(arg, str[i])) == 0){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

    int main(){
      foo("c", {"a", "b", "c"});
      return 0;
    }
```

I want to pass an array of const char* to the function directly like it is shown here. But I keep getting the error: `cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const char**'`

Comment: You should call function foo() like this: `foo("c", ["a", "b", "c"])`

Comment: @VuongHoang have you tried that? this isn't python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is a way to make that work using templates and passing C-arrays by reference, I'm not sure if that is what you really want: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e0cb5b657146ad)

In C++11 I'd much prefer to use a `std::intializer_list` to make the call `foo("c", {"a", "b", "c"})` work as intended:

```
#include <initializer_list>

bool foo(const char* arg, std::initializer_list<const char*> strings) {
    for (const char* str : strings) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

While we're at it, you should consider using C++'s string facilities over those inherited from C:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

bool foo(const std::string& arg, std::initializer_list<std::string> strings) {
    for (const auto& str : strings) {
        if (arg == str) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that a `std::initializer_list` does not own the values it provides access to, so if you want to store it, use a proper container like `std::vector` instead.

Also, if checking for the presence of `arg` in `str` is all you want to do,
why not use `std::find`?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

bool foo(const std::string& arg, std::initializer_list<std::string> strings) {
    return std::find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), arg) != strings.end();
}
```

Comment: The first option looks to fix according to my linter, but I get compile errors, according to the output I am not using c++11, on windows with cygwin64 I have g++ 4.9.3 and in opensuse VM I have g++ 5.1.1 neither of witch can compile this.

Comment: Both those compilers are capable of C++11 and beyond, but you'll have to use the `-std=c++11` compiler flag.

Comment: so its my makefile I need to change to get  c++11, thank you

Comment: plus 1 for the initializer_list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a character pointer pointer (char**) to achieve this. You cannot declare parameters as arrays, but you can pass arrays into functions, as they will be converted into double pointers.

Comment: The problem isn't with the function, the problem is trying to use `{"a", "b", "c"}` as a literal in the caller.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Since when can't you pass arrays into functions? They're automatically converted to pointers, but the declaration is still allowed.

Comment: True. I meant you can not include into the declaration of the parameters.

Comment: Technically, you can pass *references* to arrays as arguments. The syntax is a bit arcane, and I would generally avoid it, though.

Comment: That was the idea I have been meaning to convey. I don't always have to words to speak!

Answer (score 0):

Although it is recommended to drop C-style programming when using C++, and use stl containers instead, I would like to mention that the following "one-liner" works:

```
bool foo(const char* arg, const char* const* str, size_t siz) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < siz; i++)
      if (!strcmp(arg, str[i])) return true;
  return false;
}

int main() {
  cout << foo("c", array<char*, 3> { "a", "b", "c" }.data(), 3);
  system("pause");
}
```

The **surprising surprise** is that if we define the second argument of foo as `const char**`, the compiler (VS2015) yells and says:

> bool foo(...): cannot convert argument 2 from 'char **' to 'const char **'

:O
cannot convert from non-const to const??? Does that make sense anyone?

Edit: @NeilKirk explained it in his comment. Normal. Accordingly the signature should be as:

```
bool foo(const char* arg, const char* const* str, size_t siz)
```

and everything works as expected.

Comment: This does not work as intended. `sizeof(str)` will return `sizeof(char**)`, the original size of the array is lost.

Comment: guys I agree about the lost size, so I modified the code to include the size parameter. However, I am still surprised that the compiler cannot decay a non-const to const !?

Comment: `const char *text = "hi"; char *p; const char **cp = &p; *cp = text; *p = 'X';` Whoops, modified const data!

Comment: @NeilKirk you nailed it (y). I changed the definition into `bool foo(const char* arg, const char* const* str, size_t siz)` and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the array by reference via a template function, so you will be able to detect its size at compile time (note that in your case the array decays to a pointer, so `sizeof` doesn't do what you think). Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<int N>
bool foo(const char* arg, const char* (&str)[N])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (std::strcmp(arg, str[i]) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    const char* arr[] = {"abc", "de"};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << foo("de", arr);
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c26469ede9daf8a)</kbd>

And btw, try to use algorithms from the C++ standard library and `std::string` instead of `strcmp()` and raw C-strings:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool foo(const std::string arg, const std::vector<std::string>& str)
{
    return std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), arg) != str.end();
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << foo("de", {"abc", "de"});
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de05750a28765b7e)</kbd>